# NativeScript using 2way Databinding

Tags: nativescript, 2-way-object-databinding

My input isn't accepted or something is off because my code is right.

in my item-detail.component.html is this code:

```
  <StackLayout  class="nt-form chat-wrapper"  >
    <StackLayout id="chat-form" orientation="horizontal" class="nt-input input-field form">
        <TextField [(ngModel)]="usero" width="800px"  class="-rounded-lg input" hint="Nachricht" style="background-color: #ffffff;"></TextField>
        <button width="120px" class="-rounded-lg fa far fas fab" (tap)="sendMessage()" style="margin-left: 15px;" text="&#xf1d8;"></button>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

and my item-detail.component.ts is this code:

```
    import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { FormatListNumbered } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { RouterExtensions } from "@nativescript/angular";
import { resolveFileNameFromUrl } from "@nativescript/core";
import { connectableObservableDescriptor } from "rxjs/internal/observable/ConnectableObservable";
import { ChatService, DataChat } from "../shared/chat.service";
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { UserService, DataUser } from "../shared/user.service";

@Component({
    selector: "ItemDetail",
    styleUrls: ['item-detail.component.css'],
    templateUrl: "./item-detail.component.html",
    providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class ItemDetailComponent implements OnInit {
usero = "";

constructor(){};

sendMessage(): void{
        console.log("usero", this.usero);
       
    }
```

item-detail.module.ts is this:

```
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "@nativescript/angular";
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from "@nativescript/angular/common";
import { ItemDetailComponent } from "./item-detail.component";
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativeScriptFormsModule,
    NativeScriptCommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ItemDetailComponent
  ],
  schemas: [
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class ItemDetailModule { }
```

and my app.module.ts is this:

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule, NativeScriptModule } from "@nativescript/angular";
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms'

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        NativeScriptModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

So everythin that i should do is done. But for whatever reason it doesnt work the variable is empty.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting on the same issue:

In the NativeScript docs is a good doc for TextField:
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/text-field

So my textfield looks like this:

```
 <TextField  
        (textChange)="onTextChange($event)" 
        width="800px"  
        class="-rounded-lg input" 
        hint="Nachricht" 
        style="background-color: #ffffff;"
    ></TextField>
```

and my ts like this:

```
 onTextChange(args){
        let textField = <TextField>args.object;
        this.text = textField.text;
    }
```

And if the Button is pressed this function is called:

```
sendMessage(): void{
        console.log("textfield", this.text);
}
```